# Logging in multi threaded java

Tags: multithreading, logging, slf4j, logback, dropwizard

We have 12 Dropwizard Services and Each service has their own log
We used to run these services individually but now we running them as threads
We are using a multithreaded program to run all the services

Requirement:
Logs of each service should go in their corresponding logs

Problem:
Logs are merging into each other

We are using SLF4J and online research suggested use of logback but not sure how exactly to do.

Please advice

Comment: I guess you can create your own log appenders and filter the logs according to the package names. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/q46TA56CmZk

Answer (score 0):

```
Use logback.xml and MDC

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
    <property name="USER_HOME" value="C:\\logs\\analyzer" />

    <appender name="FILE-THREAD" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">

        <!-- This is MDC value -->
        <!-- We will assign a value to 'logFileName' via Java code -->
        <discriminator>
            <key>logFileName</key>
            <defaultValue>head0</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>

        <sift>

          <!-- A standard RollingFileAppender, the log file is based on 'logFileName' at runtime  -->
          <appender name="FILE-${logFileName}"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${USER_HOME}/${logFileName}.log</file>

            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>
                    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %mdc [%thread] %level %logger{35} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>

            <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
                <FileNamePattern>${USER_HOME}/${logFileName}.%i.log.zip
                </FileNamePattern>
                <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
                <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>

          </appender>

        </sift>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mkyong.proj" level="info"
        additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```